# Trigger combo box events using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code:

```
$show_location = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM location ORDER BY location_code");
  while($row_location = mysql_fetch_array($show_location))
  {
    $location_code = $row_location['location_code'];

    $show_store = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store_list WHERE location LIKE '%$location_code%'");
        $count_store = mysql_num_rows($show_store);
    while($row_store = mysql_fetch_array($show_store))
    {
        $store_name = $row_store['store_name'];
    }

    if($count_store==0)
    {
        $status = "Inactive";
        echo '<option value="'.$location_code.'">'.$location_code.'</option>';

        $sql1 = "SELECT description FROM location WHERE location_code=$location_code";
        $result1 = mysql_query("$sql1");
        $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);

        $description=$row1['description'];


    }
    else
    {
        $status = "Active";
    }

    //echo '<option value="'.$location_code.'">'.$location_code.'</option>';
  }
```

What I want to do is to display the $description somewhere in the form. I have the kind of combobox where you can select as many as you can. I want to display each $description once a location is selected. But I dont know where to put the trigger. Can sombody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

correct me if i am wrong, but will every location_code have one description right?

well there are two ways:

1) Easy but not so efficient way

Make an ajax call for every selected value.

```
$("#myDropDown").change(function (event) {
    //alert("You have Selected  :: "+$(this).val());
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajax.php",
       data: { type: "1", location: $(this).val() }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        ("#mydata").html(msg)
    });
});
```

You can check for type == 1 on php side, get the description and print it
The above method will cause a ajax request for every selection

2) A bit complex, but efficient

First of all [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) your location_code and description. It will become something like {code:"AU", description:"blah blah"}

Then use something like this

```
$("#sel").change(function(e){
    //alert($(this).val());
    var array = $(this).val();
    for(key in array){
    var json = JSON.parse(array[key]);
    $("#desiptions").html(json.description);
    }

});
```